# In Authorization & Capture process, when paypal charge the commission?

Tags: paypal

I have read documentation about Authorization and Capture process , i have something similar to, Case 1:

```
1-Your buyer orders a camera from your website.
2-Your buyer enters payment information and authorizes payment.
3-Send your buyer to PayPal using a hosted flow, specifying the variable paymentaction=authorization
4-PayPal initiates the authorization.
5-On day 29, you ship the camera and capture funds.
```

But something similar can happen, Case 2:

```
1-Your buyer orders a camera from your website.
2-Your buyer enters payment information and authorizes payment.
3-Send your buyer to PayPal using a hosted flow, specifying the variable paymentaction=authorization
4-PayPal initiates the authorization.
5-On day 25 due some reasons (customer had cancel his reservation for example) i void authorization.
```

When paypal charge his commission in Case 1 and Case 2? If i void an authorization for a customer without capture money, paypal charge anyway his commission in transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction fee should be on the Capture since that's when PayPal will know the amount that's actually being moved from one person to another.  As far as I know there isn't a fee for voiding an authorization since there was no actual money moved in the first place.